# KVO : message was received but not handled

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I'm working between `ResultDataClass` and `self`. I want to observe `xxx` property of `ResultData` and I tried the following (in `viewDidLoad`).

```
ResultDataClass *resultData = [ResultDataClass getInstance];
[resultData addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"xxx" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

I tested the observation as below.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    self.showText.text = @"test1";

    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"xxx"]) {
        self.showText.text = @"test2";
    }
}
```

But I got this

```
An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: toCalDouble
Observed object: <ResultDataClass: 0x1093845e0>
```

I googled some but still can't make it out.
Anyone know what I did wrong ??

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the view controller which observes the key of `resultData` deallocated, stop observing, or the notification would be sent to a instance which is deallocated.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    ResultDataClass *resultData = [ResultDataClass getInstance];
    [resultData removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"xxx"] ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The error was fixed but I got nothing shown in self.showText. Did I miss something?

Comment: @user What is `self.showText` ? Is it a UITextField or a UILabel ? Check if self.showText is nil and if self.showText is added to hierarchy, then check its frame, make sure it is visible.

Comment: It's a UITextView added in main.storyboard. I also use it in another method. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @user Is it modified in another method after receiving KVO notification.

Comment: It is used in another method and can be modified either before or after receiving KVO notification.